# Using the Lamar DI container, how do you build objects with a lambda given a type?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, lamar

Lamar provides the following syntax for building objects with a lambda:

```
serviceRegistry.For<ISomeType>().Use(x => { ... });
```

This would allow you to resolve ISomeType which would execute the registered delegate:

```
 var someType = container.GetInstance<ISomeType>();
```

Is there a non-generic equivalent such as the following?

```
serviceRegistry.For(typeof(ISomeType)).Use(x => { ... });
```

I'm not seeing an overload for this.

Comment: If you look at the source code, you will see that the desired syntax is not possible since the `Use` member for that `For` does not allow a generic call https://github.com/JasperFx/lamar/blob/master/src/Lamar/ServiceRegistry.cs#L93

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there a particular reason for wanting the desired syntax?

Comment: Nice ... never heard of the XY problem.  I've often encountered whatever the corollary would be (the YX solution?) where you ask how to do X and someone recommends doing Y instead, assuming you don't have a valid reason for X.

Comment: `public object GetInstance(Type serviceType)` [source code](https://github.com/JasperFx/lamar/blob/master/src/Lamar/IoC/Scope.cs#L140) `(ISomeType)container.GetInstance(typeof(ISomeType))`

Answer (score 1):

After discovering that Lamar's `ServiceRegistry` is derived from `ServiceProvider`, I realized that it would be possible to achieve this by using the ServiceProvider API:

```
var container = new Container(x => x.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(string), sp => "test", ServiceLifetime.Singleton)));
Console.WriteLine(container.GetService<string>());
```

[See .Net Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8H4Bce)